# Best practise for developing and deploying ASP.NET Applications?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, environment

I'm quite new to programming. I have an ASP.NET 4.0 application and I would like some guidelines and best practise for how to dev, test and deploy it with regards to environment configuration.

I am currently manually changing my Web.Config file when I've finished a round of development, I then publish it to the web server using Visual Studio.

For example in my Web.Config should I define the connection strings for my dev/test/prod SQL Server databases in there? How should I configure Visual Studio? Are there any good articles on this that you could recommend?

The source code is kept in SVN, which is checked in using Tortoise SVN.

Thanks,
Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen people keep files `web.config.dev` and `web.config.live` in the repository and then rename it to `web.config` when deployed.

Comment: automate this with a build/deploy script and you have a good solution